# Prevent trailing slash which included at the end of the URL

Tags: iis

From a security perspective there is need be to disable directory browsing for us, however we have been disabled this feature from the `IIS`, but it redirects directory requests with 301 (move permanent) by adding trailing slash at the end of the URL.

In this way hackers may aware of directories and sub-directories locations which we don't like it!

How do prevent adding trailing slash at the end of the URL for existing directories?

Comment: Yes but the question .... NO , I modified it. :)

Comment: As far as I know, if we disable directory browsing in the iis, the IIS will return 403 Forbidden error in the page not redirect with 301. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh467.png) Did you add some custom error page or speical redirect rule in your application?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using [HttpApplication.BeginRequest Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest?view=netframework-4.7.2) . when a request for a directory arrived, checking directory existence in location of given `Request.PhysicalPath` specifies that the request is for directory or not.

I share the code, maybe helps someone:

```
public void OnApplicationBeginRequest(HttpApplication app)
{
        if (app.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath!="/"&& System.IO.Directory.Exists(app.Request.PhysicalPath))
        {
            app.Response.StatusCode = 404;
            app.CompleteRequest();
        }
}
```

However this worked for me perfectly but perhaps there is a better solution using IIS modules which I'm so excited to know. :)